# Magical Record not compiling

Tags: ios, cocoa, compiler-errors, magicalrecord

I am new to Xcode, C, Objective-C and I have this error of compilation for Magical Record.
The project given with the sources is compiling, only my project is not.

Does the following error give enough information to get any help ?

[image: The error given by Xcode]

Thanks !

PS : I am also using mogenerator.

Comment: The problem seems to be somewhere else. Do you have a more detailed debug console output?

Comment: What version number do you see if you choose “About Xcode” from the Xcode menu? Also, what SDK version are you using?

Comment: My Xcode is 4.6.2 and the SDK of the project is OS X SDK 10.7 ! @pedro.m. : I dont have console outputs since the project is not compiling...

Comment: I found the solution : the base SDK was set to OSX 10.7. If I change it to 10.8, it works !

Comment: @Colas: Yup; `NS_OPTIONS` requires the 10.8 SDK. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NS_OPTIONS` requires the 10.8 SDK. That's why !
So, the base SDK has to be set to 10.8.